# How can I check if a variable is neither null or the empty string with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have been doing the following:

```
if (json.RowKeyNew != "") {
    updateGridMeta(entity, json.PartitionKey, json.RowKeyNew, row, tab);
}
```

However if the json.RowKeyNew is null then the if condition is met which is not what I want. How can I check for something that is not null and not "" ?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (json.RowKeyNew != undefined && json.RowKeyNew != "") {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
if (json.RowKeyNew) {
    updateGridMeta(entity, json.PartitionKey, json.RowKeyNew, row, tab);
}
```

Comment: What if `json.RowKeyNew` is the number zero?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (json.RowKeyNew)
```

just put varible in if condition it return true if having some value else return false